# iOS: UITableview.performBatchUpdates causes jump of tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview with multiple sections and multiple row count in each section. E.g. In one cell I have a button that changes the row count.

When this happens I call

```
 tableView?.performBatchUpdates({
           tableView?.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
        }, completion: { (success) in })
```

So the numberOfRowAtIndexPath changes and a new cell is inserted or the last cell is removed.

My problem is that the whole tableviewcontent seams to jump some millimeters to the top and down again.

At the same time I receive a autolayout error which forces my tableviewHeaderView to the width of zero. Maybe this is the reason for the jump. I don't know where width = 0 comes from.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285500 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa8dd77a700]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fa8dd77a510 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002906d0 UIView:0x7fa8dd77a510.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000007ad040'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002891a0 UILayoutGuide:0x6000007ad040'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing >= UILabel:0x7fa8dd777950'Abnahme'.trailing + 16   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000289560 H:[UIView:0x7fa8dd77a700]-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fa8dd777950'MyLabel']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00009fea0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' MyApp.MyTableHeaderView:0x7fa8dd776670.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002905e0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000007ad040'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':MyApp.MyTableHeaderView:0x7fa8dd776670 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000287b20 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000007ad040'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':MyApp.MyTableHeaderView:0x7fa8dd776670 )>"
)
```